# Iframe with Wordpress height not working on mobile

Tags: html, iframe

I'm Iframing a wordpress blog, I set the height to 600px, but it is not accepting it and it is overflowing showing the entire blog by roughly 3000px in height... give or take. If you view it on a phone: http://www.garfield-county.com/emergency-management/index.aspx

It looks great/fine and normal on browsers though, here's my code:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td height="600px">
            <div style="height:600px">
                <center>
                    <iframe style='width:520px; height:550px; max-height:600px;' src='https://garfieldcounty.wordpress.com/' scrolling='yes' frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true' allowfullscreen='false' ></iframe>
               </center>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I created a `div` that didn't work, and `td` height didn't work either.

Comment: On which platforms does this happen?

Comment: So far just Iphone/IOS  I don't have a droid to test it with at the moment

Comment: Smells like an iOS specific weirdness.

Comment: Duplicate not perfectly exact but should solve the problem

Comment: Awesome thank you I did do a search must not have been specific enough, the fix was adding "overflow: auto;" and "-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;"  to the div tag style